# Dependencies via Rally Excel plug-in

Tags: excel, ms-office, rally

I'm trying to retried dependency information for a set of User Stories via the Rally Excel plug-in. I don't see Predecessors,Successors in the Columns box under Manage Queries.

Anyone know how I can retrieve that data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though they don't show up as selectable columns in the dialog, you can still type in Predecessors and Successors in the Columns list:

[image: Predecessors Successors Manual Entry]

And they'll show up as results in your worksheet:

[image]